# Trigger a DAG on Tuesday after 3rd Saturday of every month

Tags: python, cron, calendar, airflow

I want to trigger an AirFlow DAG on Tuesday after 3rd Saturday of every month using crons expression. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

0 8 * * 2 - Not sure what should be the third field (Day of the month) in my case.

Comment: `0 0 12 ? 1/1 TUE#3 *` will run on the 3rd Tuesday every month, not sure if cron supports the Tuesday after the third saturday

Comment: I want dag to be triggered on Tuesday after 3rd Staurday. Anyway Thanks.